# Flickering water effect

Tags: xna, effects, water

I have downloaded completely different samples with water effects (in XNA) and I've noticed that they all exhibit a common problem: when the camera direction (only the direction, not the position)  moves, a noticable and annoying flicker occurs where the water meets terrain. I'm curios to find out more about this. Why does it happen? Does it have a name? And what can I do about it?

Comment: Wild guess: maybe your near plane is too close to the camera. This limits the effective resolution of the Z buffer.

Comment: Could you link to one of these samples?

Answer (score 3):

It's named **Z-fighting**. You can google a lot information about it. For example [here on wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). In short: your water and terrain plane are in the same distance from camera (they are coplanar). If you move your camera (direction), float results differ a bit, so sometimes (I mean: some pixels) it chooses water to be drawn, sometimes it chooses terrain.

And you can solve this problem easily - just move your water plane a bit above or under the terrain, if they have the same "height" (they are coplanar).

Comment: But the terrain and the water are not "particulary" coplanar. I've tried to put spheres in the water with 1/4 of them abouve the water and got the same effect too? Althogh I may really be plain z-fighting I'm seeing (which I do know about) - I have no clue on how to fix tihs (and neither have the authors of those effects I've tried, I gusee. Or it doesn't bother them...)

Comment: The above guess is probably the best one given the details we have. We need a picture or video

Comment: No. It is not Z-fighting. If it were Z-fighting I would see it on pixel level. But the effect I asked about (and see in several samples) seems rether to happen on a vertex level. Once I figured out how to do recording I'll be back!

Comment: You can use this online service for recording apps or desktop: http://www.screenr.com/

Answer (score 0):

It is floating-point prcision error, you can fix that by not changing view matrix, if it has change only for little, if X or Y mouse rotation is less then 0.1 then use old view.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can also be solved by using a logrithmic z-buffer which can be done in your shader, and is very very easy to implement.

Comment: More details would make this a better answer.